# Spark JDBC Postgresql Overwrite job - minimise downtime of target table

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, pyspark, jdbc, apache-spark-sql

I want to overwrite a `Postgresql` table `transactionStats` which is used by the customer facing dashboards.

This table needs to be updated every 30 mins. I will write a AWS Glue Spark job via JDBC connection to perform this operation.

Spark dataframe write snippet -

```
df.write.format("jdbc").option("url", "connection_params").option("dbtable","public.transactionStats"). mode("overwrite").save()
```

My question is - if i overwrite this table will it cause downtime to the customers while the table is being overwritten?

If yes, how to avoid downtime? Any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes when overwriting with spark SQL datasource you will affect your users query using the table.

By design spark jdbc driver is meant for parallel insert (see numPartitions parrameter) and thus the executors have their own connection to the database, while the drivers runs ddl (such drop table, truncate, create)

As a result there is multiple connections involved during an overwrite table, and this cannot be done in a single transaction (as it could be done with a regular sql script), leading to unexpected behavior for users.

Keep in mind you would also loose the indexes on the table after the process. You could use the overwrite mode together with truncate option to avoid dropping the table, but again you would have a downtime see
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-32595

A alternate design would be to load your data in a temporary table from scratch, create the indexes if needed, and then in a single transaction with a jdbc statement, drop the previous table and rename the temporary one to replace the previous.

Last advice, spark jdbc itself is not particularly good at dealing with postgresql, because it relies on regular jdbc data transfers with lot of serialization/deserialization. For very large dataset prefer the postgres copy from / copy to statements based on CSV. And CSV is a topic where spark shines.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I will go with the alternate design. how can i run a single transaction with spark jdbc to drop and rename tables?

Comment: You won't use spark jdbc but basic java jdbc, from scala or java. Spark itself can deal with ddl with jdbc catalog but again, not in a single transaction.

Comment: @SiddharthKanojiya does this answer your question - if so can you mark it as solving ?

Comment: it did solve. Thank you. wrote a python code using pyscopy2 to do drop & replace a single transactions. Works great. Won't dropping the previous table again cause downtime to users ? is it a common practice ?